# Slickgrid custom cell titles

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I use shortened enums as cell values, but I'd like to show the description for the enum in a tooltip, which uses cell's title. This is why I need to edit cell's title.

I can't find any way to access the cell's HTML-element with Slickgrid. The cells already have a title, which is it's column's title. I don't remember putting those titles there, so I guess it's some Slickgrid-stuff.

I use JQuery's tooltip-plugin for showing other tooltips.

**Is there any way to edit specific cell's title?**

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Comment: I managed to do this. I'm posting my answer and give you feedback next sunday or monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get cell's HTML-element with:

```
grid.getCellNode(rowIndex, cellIndex)
```

You can then edit the title of a cell with:

```
grid.getCellNode(rowIndex, cellIndex).title = "foo"
```

If you are using jQuery you can also do:

```
$(grid.getCellNode(rowIndex, cellIndex)).attr("title", "foo")
```

If you are using SlickGrid's AutoToolTip-plugin, editing the titles of cells won't work, because the AutoToolTip-plugin overwrites the title always when hovering a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
$("#myGrid .slick-cell").each(function(item){
    $(this).attr('title',generateTooltip($(this).text()));                 
    $(this).tooltip();
});

function generateTooltip(value){
    //return appropriate description based on the enum that is stored in 'value'
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Accessing cells through jQuery isn't such a good idea because SlickGrid offers a method to get specific cell's HTML-element (see the post below). You could also give titles only to cells which are hovered on instead of looping through all of them.